# How hard will it be to go from symfony2 to symfony 1?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony, symfony-1.4

I know symfony2 and never used symfony1.4.
I am going to new company but don't know if they use symfony2 or symfony1.4.

I want to know that if they did use symfony1.4 , how hard it be to make transition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Symfony2 and symfony differ completely in code base, but from an architectural point of view especially in the "wiring" of the core classes.

As Symfony2 has its Dependency Injection Container (DIC) to handle service classes and their dependencies, symfony 1.4 has a sfContext singleton that handles the different classes that somewhat can be configured inside the factories.yml config files, but not at all that flexible as in Symfony2.

On the other side, the MVC concept is still quite common between the two versions. You have a routing component (with a slightly different syntax) that maps URLs to controllers. In controllers you handle the request and prepare the data needed in the view. Templates in symfony 1.4 are plain php files (no twig). ORMs supported in 1.4 are doctrine 1.2 and propel (I believe 1.6). Also the form handling and security component are different in both versions.

But that's all more or less "detail". The most important question is what you gonna do with it. If the application itself is straight forward stuff you should be able to get into 1.4 quite fast, if you have to get into the internals you will discover more differences in concept and limitations.

To get a feeling you can have a look at the jobeet tutorial for 1.4: http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/

Find more about the differences in the official documentation of v2: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/symfony1.html

Answer (score 3):

symfony1.4 is completely different from Symfony2.

They're basically 2 separate frameworks that only share the name.

Also when comparing symfony versions you'll have to keep in mind that most of the components it uses got updated as well. Doctrine, for example, got rewritten as well and they use completely different design patterns (Active Record in 1.x vs Data Mapper in 2.x).

That all said, 1.4 is much easier to learn (in my subjective opinion), so if you really know your way around symfony2, learning 1.4 shouldn't be hard or long.

If they really use older version, you could also consider persuading people in new company to switch to newer version, as symfony 1.4 soon won't even be supported.